# I'm lost as to why this query is failing

Tags: mysql, odbc

When I run the following simple query:

```
UPDATE tournaments SET player_clubs = '175,318' WHERE id = 3437;
```

It results in the following error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.6.41-84.1-56-log]Lost connection to MySQL server during query

/grassroots/include/database_access.asp, line 66
```

If I open up mySQL Workbench and run the query directly against the DB it works just fine. Why?

Comment: On a different note: Dont store the values as comma separated. You should consider normalizing your table structure. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: This is not a useful comment. The list of clubs is a transient field, used only while completing a task and then discarded. It makes zero sense to build out an entirely new table to store this information. I would like an answer to my actual problem/question. It is not always the right answer to just normalize everything.